Method with() of eloquent orm don't works with another method
I'm trying to translate the relations that I have in my laravel 8 project to the eloquent orm. It's a simple relation but I don't know why when I try to filter the query I get null in the second table.
My Model Cita: (Appointment in English)
class Cita extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'citas';

    public function user() {
        return $this->BelongsTo(User::class, 'id_vete', 'id');
    }

    public function evento() {
       return $this->belongsTo(Evento::class, 'id_evento', 'id');
    }

My Model Evento: (Event in English)
class Evento extends Model {

    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'eventos';

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_usu', 'id');
    }

    public function citas() {
        return $this->hasMany(Cita::class, 'id_evento', 'id');
    }

My original CitaController that works without problem:
 public function index(){

        $idVete = session('user_id'); // Get the ID of the current User

       $citas = Cita::where('id_vete', $idVete)
        ->join('eventos', 'eventos.id', '=', 'citas.id_evento')
        ->join('clientes', 'clientes.dni', '=', 'citas.dni_cliente')
        ->select('citas.id AS cita_id', 'citas.dia', 'citas.hora', 'citas.descripcion', 'citas.active',
          'clientes.first_nm', 'clientes.last_nm', 'clientes.dni', 'clientes.email', 'clientes.phone', 
          'servicios.id', 'servicios.nm_evento')
        ->get();


And I basically I want this:
$citas = Cita::with(['evento', 'user'])->get();
Result:
[
{
"id": 3,
"id_vete": 2,
"id_evento": 2,
"dni_cliente": "65495321",
"dia": "2023-03-16",
"hora": "19:00:00",
etc...
"evento": {
"id": 2,
"id_usu": 2,
etc...
},
"user": {
"id": 2,
"name": "Admin",
etc...
}
But when I try to put some filter plus the method with() for example
$citas = Cita::with(['evento', 'user'])->where('id_vete', $idVete)->get();
I get:
[]

What if you switch the user and cita? Because you're looking for citas for a specific user: User::with(['citas.evento'])->where('id', $idVete)->get() should do the trick as well.

query seemed to correct.But make sure that you are passing an existing $idVete to the last eloquent query.

Try using this
$citas = Cita::with('user')->with(['evento' => function($q) use($idVete) { 
       $q->where('id', $idVete);
}])->get();

Or
$citas = Cita::with(['evento', 'user'])->where('evento.id_vete', $idVete)->get();


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
